# Postfix, MSA, Smarthost, and LAN

Tags: postfix, email-server, smarthost, hp-modular-smart-array

I've, let's say, 5 servers. They are either public and private or only private (network), they all send e-mails, either system e-mails (local mailbox) or installed application (wiki, issues tracker, etc.).

And I've a 6th which I want to use as "central" server.

The idea is to configure all the server to send their e-mail to the 6th which will either deliver e-mails directly, or transfer them to third party (like mandrill, my isp, or someone which will take care of configure all delivery things (spf, domainkeys, etc.)

1. How do I need to configure the 5 servers?
2. How do I need to configure the "central server"?

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The five servers are configured to use the central server as a relay. The main change from the defaults to achieve that is the definition of a relayhost:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf:
# <snip>
# (deliver via mailhub)
relayhost = [central.server.example.com]
```

The central server needs to be configured to accept mail for local delivery for your domain as well as allow relaying smtp mail for those 5 servers.

Again the main changes from the default:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf:
# <snip>
# The inet_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
# addresses that this mail system receives mail on.
inet_interfaces = all
myhostname = central.server.example.com
mydomain = example.com
# The ip-addresses we relay for:
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.3
```